# Is it possible to get specific attribute form an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, svg, delimiter

I have the following object being passed to me inside an array to a function:

```
[ { id: 'WA1WA1WAbWA2WAaWAbWA9WA6-WAdWA2WAaWAd-4WAbWAcWA3-WAbWA3WA7WAa-WAcWAbWA8WA9WAcWA9WA9WA9WA3WA3WA3WA9',
obj: '<svg data="BusinessProductFigure" x="484.171875" y="123" id="WA1WA1WAbWA2WAaWAbWA9WA6-WAdWA2WAaWAd-4WAbWAcWA3-WAbWA3WA7WAa-    WAcWAbWA8WA9WAcWA9WA9WA9WA3WA3WA3WA9" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><rect x="4" y="4" 
 width="60" height="14" fill="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-width="1"/></svg>' } ]
```

Is is possible to get the X and Y value in separate variables which are within the SVG tag? Are there any conditions or delimiters that can be used somehow?

Comment: use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse it and then read the values from the DOM.

Comment: @RobertLongson I got the document, but how do I access individual variables now?

Comment: I figured it out. Just used doc.getElementsByTagName["svg"].getAttribute("x"); Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) like so:

```js
var x = [ { id: 'WA...',
            obj: '<svg data="BusinessProductFigure" x="484.171875" y="123" id="WA..."  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><rect x="4" y="4" width="60" height="14" fill="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-width="1"/></svg>' } ]
           
var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(x[0].obj, 'image/svg+xml');

alert(dom.documentElement.getAttribute("x"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 'JKIU',
  obj: '<svg data="BusinessProductFigure" x="484.171875" y="123" id="FRRR" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" > <rect x="4" y="4" width="60" height="14" fill="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="rgb(299,299,162)" stroke-width="1"/></svg>'
}];

var div = document.createElement('div');

div.innerHTML = arr[0].obj;

// var svg = div.querySelector('svg');
var svg = div.firstChild;

var x = svg.getAttribute('x');
var y = svg.getAttribute('y');

console.log(x, y);
```

Comment: Instead of `querySelector` you could just do `firstChild`